# Activate SP Server Publishing Infrastructure on Online Publishing Site -modern XP

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-site, feature-activation, features

I have a problem when trying to enable SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure site coll feature on one of my site... I know this has been discussed many times, but even when triying every solution I got my fingers on, I still have an error.

Let me explain :

**What I have and what I want:**

on https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite, my users would like to have Wiki Pages library AND multilingual feature.
And i know for both of them, you have to enable SharePoint Server Publishing on the targeted site.

**What I tried**

1. I tried by going into site settings > Site features > SharePoint Server Publishing > Activate
   It gave me the error "This feature depends on The "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature". It has to be enabled on the site collection" I read somewhere that this error can show up because you do not have the rights permissions.
2. So, as a SharePoint Administrator, I went in SP admin and I set my user as "Main administrator". I am one of the Collection site admin as well.
3. Now, still on MySite (https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite),I tried to enable the Sharepoint Server Publishing Infrastructure under the "Site COllection Feature" and it gave me an "Unexpected error" with a correlation ID.

(as we are online, normally there is no more such things as Site Collections. And, **I do not want to enable this feature for WHOLE TENANT**)

(as we are online, I don't even see WHY it is still running with correlation IDs)

So, has anyone any idea on how to perform this ?
**How to enable SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on Online Publishing Site** ?

Pretty Please ?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is a Site Collection -- they always exist, even online.

And in SharePoint Online, machine translation was made unavailable in Sept 2018. See [Create a multi-language website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-multi-language-website-DA0B5614-8CF5-4905-A44C-90C2B3F8FBB6).

The suggested replacement is to leverage the [Translator Text API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/translator-api/).